# Code document dialog in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Where is the option that I can turn on the code documentation dialog box  in Eclipse.

I Googled it but I can't find anything.  If I want to search better I don't know what should I search?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'turn on'? If documentation is available for a class/method, just hover the class/method and the dialog will pop up.

Comment: but for me it isn't pop up!

Answer (score 0):

`Window > Preferences`, `Java > Editor > Hovers`, `Javadoc` (because what you see is the Javadoc).

If you want it on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> you will find it unter `Java > Editor > Content Assist`.

For this the Javadoc or the source code has to be available. For JDK classes there is a nasty default setting of Eclipse preventing this. Eclipse uses the JRE it runs on as default Java environment; the JRE comes without source. So you should change it to the JDK at `Java > Installed JREs`.

For Android classes it should work out of the box, regardless of the JRE/JDK used.

Comment: it is set on jdk and javaoc is say: Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Comment: What class specifically? One of the Android API as in your screenshot?